# How to use ADO Rest API to get the list of test run in a specific build

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

From the ADO Rest API,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1,can you please tell me how can I get the list of tests and their results of a specific build?

In summary, I am looking for the information in 'test' tab of a particular build via REST API:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use [Runs - Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) api and pass the optional build id to get the test run ID in the build:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?minLastUpdatedDate={minLastUpdatedDate}&maxLastUpdatedDate={maxLastUpdatedDate}&buildIds={buildIds}&api-version=6.0
```

Then use [Results - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) api to get the test results of the test run:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=6.0
```

Comment: if I specify `BuildId`, do i still need to provide `minLastUpdatedDate={minLastUpdatedDate}&maxLastUpdatedDate={maxLastUpdatedDate}` in  Runs - Query api ?

Comment: If you don't specify `minLastUpdatedDate={minLastUpdatedDate}&maxLastUpdatedDate={maxLastUpdatedDate}`, you'll get a lot of test runs.

Comment: Each test run under a job. And each job has its own log file. I see there is an api to get the log for a build. But  how can get the `log id` for a job of a test ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20log?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Comment: You could use [Builds - Get Build Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20logs?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to get log id.