# How to get the number of jobs in build result page?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

A follow up on my previous questions [How to use ADO Rest API to get the list of test run in a specific build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65299846/how-to-use-ado-rest-api-to-get-the-list-of-test-run-in-a-specific-build).

I use Runs - Query api to get runs of my build:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?minLastUpdatedDate={minLastUpdatedDate}&maxLastUpdatedDate={maxLastUpdatedDate}&buildIds={buildIds}&api-version=6.0
```

But I see that the `count` value in the JSON body does not match with the # of job I see in the build result page, i.e. `https://{my org}.visualstudio.com/{my project}/_build/results?buildId={my build id}&view=results`

From the build result page, I only have 5 jobs.  Can you please help me in how to get the # of job in the build result page?

Moreover, each job has a log. How to get the log id of each job so that I can use this api `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20log?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you please help me in how to get the # of job in the build result page?

The `#number` in the Build Result Page is the [Build Number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) of the Build Pipeline.

To Get this number, you could use the Rest API: [Builds - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=6.1-preview.6
```

Then you could Check the `buildNumber` field in the Response.

[image]

[image]

> How to get the log id of each job so that I can use this api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20log?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

To Get the LogId for each job, you need to use this Rest API: [Timeline - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/timeline?api-version=4.1
```

**Note:** If you do not enter a specific timelineid, you will get the timeline of the entire build

Then you can find the corresponding logid based on the job name(e.g. Agent Job 1) or identifier Name(e.g. Job_2,Job_1)

[image]